# Spring-Boot include build-info as SpringProperty in Logback

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1 with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `git-commit-id-plugin` to automatically populate the actuator info endpoint with the build information. Works great. I'm getting the values grouped under the json properites `build` and `git`.

Now I also want to include these information in the json formatted log messages (using logback logstash). Therefore I tried using the `springProperty` extension, but it seems that these elements are not available as environment entries.

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="info_version" source="info.build.version"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="build_version" source="build.version"/>
```

I both cases nothing gets resolved. I also tried to add the `build-info.properties` as a property source manually by

```
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties")
```

...but this doesn't seem to work neither.

Thus, how can I include properties like the build-version, git-commit or something else from info entries in the log messages?

Comment: I have a similar propblem where I try to access the git.commit.id.abbrev defined in git.properties within logback-spring.xml (it doesn't work). I suspect this is because Logback is initialized before the loading of git.properties in the environment. If I set git.commit.id.abbrev to some arbitrary value in bootstrap.yml, then I can use it Logback (not a solution unfortunately).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible as you describe. As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration:

> Since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created, it is not possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring @Configuration files. The only way to change the logging system or disable it entirely is via System properties.

I believe the `git.properties` and `build-info.properties` are included in the Environment too late and their values cannot be used during Logback initialization (this also explains why `@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties")` doesn't work either).

You might be able to inject the build info in `logback-spring.xml` at build time using Maven's resource filtering mechanism.

## EDIT 1:

I've been able to inject the commit ID in `logback-spring.xml` using Maven resource filtering

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
```

and then in `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    <version>@git.commit.id.abbrev@</version>
</encoder>
```

## EDIT 2:

Another (better) solution referenced in the comment by @Leikingo is to import `git.properties` in the logback config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property resource="git.properties" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="application_name" source="spring.application.name" />
    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <version>${git.commit.id.abbrev}</version>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Great. Works like charm. I did the resource filtering in the past but totally forgot about this. Btw. I also found another way, at least for the `git.properties`. Using a regular logback properties import `<property resource="git.properties" />`. Then you can reference the id with `${git.commit.id.abbrev}`.

Comment: Cool, that's even better than Maven filtering!